# Dimension of the sum of subespaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V_1$ and $V_2$ be two subspaces of a vector space of finite-dimension, such that $$\mbox{dim}(V_1+V_2)\ =\ \mbox{dim}(V_1\cap V_2) + 1,$$
show that $V_1 \subseteq V_2$ or $V_2 \subseteq V_1$.

Please help me with this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\mathsf{Hint}$. Write $V_1=U\oplus (V_1\cap V_2)$ and $V_2=W\oplus (V_1\cap V_2)$. Then $V_1+V_2=U\oplus V\oplus (V_1\cap V_2)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that 
$$\dim(V_1\cap V_2)\le\dim V_1\le\dim(V_1+V_2)=1+\dim(V_1\cap V_2).$$
It follows that either
$$\dim V_1=\dim(V_1\cap V_2) \Rightarrow V_1\subseteq V_2,$$ 
or
$$\dim V_1=\dim(V_1+V_2)\Rightarrow V_2\subseteq V_1.$$

Answer (score 1):

$\mbox{dim}(V_1+V_2)\ =\ \mbox{dim}(V_1\cap V_2) + 1,$ means that base of $(V_1+V_2)$ has only one element more than $(V_1\cap V_2)$ then this one extra base must be belong to $V_1$ or $V_2$ so

$V_1$ is subspace of $V_2$

or $V_2$ is subspace of $V_1$